# Is a range of values from an exponential distribution still exponentially distributed?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, exponential-family, bounds

I have to generate numbers of two different exponential distribution ($e_1, e_2$) with parameters respectively  $\lambda_1$ and  $\lambda_2 = k \lambda_1$, with $0<k<1$. 
But I also want to discard all the values from $e_1$ larger than $B$ and also discard all the values from $e_2$ smaller than $B$.

My question is: are these two sets of numbers still exponentially distributed? And in case, do they have the same   $\lambda_1$ and  $\lambda_2 = k \lambda_1$ parameters?

Comment: Which two sets?  The original ones are exponentially distributed by construction, whereas after censoring them at $B,$ neither can possibly be exponentially distributed because all exponential variables are supported on $[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they’re not exponentially distributed any more. Plot their histograms to convince yourself. There are special cases though. If $B<0$, $e_2$ will still be exponential because you drop no samples.

Comment: I expected that. Thanks